Spring Cloud Gateway with Spring Security for Register / Login using JWT Authententication. 403 Forbidden Error
I'm learning SpringBoot for a microservice application project.
I'm using Keycloak Client Authentication Route with Service Accounts Role and I've added the keycloak Configuration to the API Gateway Service application.properties.
Here's the API Gateway Security Config:

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity){

        serverHttpSecurity
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                        .pathMatchers(
                                "/api/**",
                                "/eureka/**"
                        )
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated())
                .csrf()
                .disable()

                .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt);
        return serverHttpSecurity.build();
    }

}

Now I'm creating an Identity Service Application that handles user registration and login apart from the User Service for user management. This service utilizes JWT Authentication with Spring Security AuthenticationProvider, JwtFilter and UserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.
Following is the Identity Service Security Config.

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {


    private final JwtFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeRequests(request -> request.regexMatchers(
                        "/api/auth/*",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/v3/api-docs",
                        "/v3/api-docs/*",
                                "/swagger-resources/",
                                "/swagger-resources/*",
                                "/configuration/ui",
                                "/configuration/security",
                                "/swagger-ui/",
                                "/webjars/*",
                                "/swagger-ui.html"
                        )
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(
                        session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}


Register / Localhost
This is the endpoint, on executing a postman POST Request using OAuth2.0 with the JWT Token, I'm getting 403: Forbidden as response.
Following is the log from API Gateway Service:
2024-04-12 20:15:02.924 TRACE [xpense-gateway,,] 35685 --- [     parallel-8] o.s.c.g.h.p.PathRoutePredicateFactory    : Pattern "[/eureka/web]" does not match against value "/api/auth/register"
2024-04-12 20:15:02.924 TRACE [xpense-gateway,,] 35685 --- [     parallel-8] o.s.c.g.h.p.PathRoutePredicateFactory    : Pattern "/api/auth/**" matches against value "/api/auth/register"
2024-04-12 20:15:02.924 DEBUG [xpense-gateway,,] 35685 --- [     parallel-8] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: identity-service
2024-04-12 20:15:02.924 DEBUG [xpense-gateway,,] 35685 --- [     parallel-8] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: POST http://localhost:8080/api/auth/register] to Route{id='identity-service', uri=lb://identity-service, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/api/auth/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[SpringCloudCircuitBreakerResilience4JFilterFactory name = 'resilience', fallback = /identity-fallback], order = 0]], metadata={}}
2024-04-12 20:15:02.924 DEBUG [xpense-gateway,,] 35685 --- [     parallel-8] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [ade0fee6-4] Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@56568494
2024-04-12 20:15:02.924 DEBUG [xpense-gateway,,] 35685 --- [     parallel-8] o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted gatewayFilterFactories: [[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@7a3a49e5}, order = -2147483648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@305881b8}, order = -2147482648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@6dbb3d7d}, order = -1], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@3ea9a091}, order = 0], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@26495639}, order = 0], [[SpringCloudCircuitBreakerResilience4JFilterFactory name = 'resilience', fallback = /identity-fallback], order = 0], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@6c1b82cd}, order = 10000], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter@54687fd0}, order = 10150], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.LoadBalancerServiceInstanceCookieFilter@6eaf030c}, order = 10151], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@16f4a3c0}, order = 2147483646], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@b2da3a5}, order = 2147483647], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@acd3460}, order = 2147483647]]
2024-04-12 20:15:02.924 TRACE [xpense-gateway,ffa6cb10b03275d4,5984f380554abaa0] 35685 --- [     parallel-8] o.s.c.g.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter   : RouteToRequestUrlFilter start
2024-04-12 20:15:02.924 TRACE [xpense-gateway,ffa6cb10b03275d4,5984f380554abaa0] 35685 --- [     parallel-8] s.c.g.f.ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter : ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter url before: lb://identity-service/api/auth/register
2024-04-12 20:15:02.925 TRACE [xpense-gateway,ffa6cb10b03275d4,5984f380554abaa0] 35685 --- [     parallel-8] s.c.g.f.ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter : LoadBalancerClientFilter url chosen: http://VFIEVOX3.Router:35185/api/auth/register
2024-04-12 20:15:02.945 TRACE [xpense-gateway,,] 35685 --- [r-http-epoll-11] o.s.c.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter  : outbound route: dc99dbca, inbound: [ade0fee6-4] 
2024-04-12 20:15:02.951 TRACE [xpense-gateway,,] 35685 --- [r-http-epoll-11] o.s.c.g.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter  : NettyWriteResponseFilter start inbound: dc99dbca, outbound: [ade0fee6-4] 
2024-04-12 20:15:02.952 TRACE [xpense-gateway,,] 35685 --- [r-http-epoll-11] o.s.c.g.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter      : spring.cloud.gateway.requests tags: [tag(httpMethod=POST),tag(httpStatusCode=403),tag(outcome=CLIENT_ERROR),tag(routeId=identity-service),tag(routeUri=lb://identity-service),tag(status=FORBIDDEN)]


I know that the KeyCloak mechanism can handle user authentication but I'm trying to build my own mechanism in place in the service from scratch to handle user authentication and authorization.
I tried going through the documentation for Spring Security but I'm getting confused now as I'm not clear on how exactly SecurityFilterChain and SecurityWebFilterChain.
SecurityWebFilterChain provides Oauth2ResourceServer with ServerHttpSecurity but it does not handle SessionManagement and sessionCreation which I'm looking forward to implement.
Thank you in advance.

Why have you built a custom JWTFilter? Why are you not using the spring oauth2resourceserver filter? Is your homemade filter more secure than the one that is provided by the framework?

I am pretty sure my custom filter is not better than the oauth2resourceserver. I am trying to have custom implementation that involves generation of the token alongside other mechanisms such as email account activation using activation code and so on.

i would then suggest to use a onAuthentication hook instead, your flow is very unclear, you are using client credential authentication, that is authenticate service to service (microservice to microservice not browser), exactly what oauth2ResourceServer is constructed for. But then you are talking about session management and session creation.  Here you should read up on the BFF pattern, and not to be rude but i would suggest you read a lot more about oauth and especially open id connect if you want to learn. And dont write custom security, use the tools built into spring security.

there are great resources out there for instance, that is free https://spring.academy/

Alright I will look into it. I just started learning springboot and Im kinda overwhelmed by the vastness. The reason I implemented Keycloak was to handle Application level authentication. On the other hand, JWT with spring security for user level authentication mechanism. I can send you the repo on git if you wanna maybe take a look at the codebase meanwhile.

No i will not go through any github code etc. me like many others have jobs, and spend the little spare time we have answering well defined questions, that have proper research, and single answers. Stack overflow is a Q/A site, not a forum, if you are seeking, reviews, discussions etc. I would advice you to other sites, or discord servers etc. Security is an advanced topic, and you should really become friends with the official docs. Read the architecture chapters. And dont use JWTs, start out with simple FormLogin and learn how it works. Good luck

You are trying to build enterprise without knowledge of how things like BASIC-security, FormLogin (session based authentication using cookies), Certificate based authentication, or things like SAML etc work. Start simple (basic) then implement intermediate (FormLogin) then learn oauth.

I figured out the problem and why it was getting stuck. Thank you for your help and time,

The issue in the code configuration was with the order of the of the web filter chain mechanism.
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
  httpSecurity
    .authorizeRequests(request -> request.regexMatchers(
      "/api/auth/*",
      "/v2/api-docs",
      "/v3/api-docs",
      "/v3/api-docs/*",
      "/swagger-resources/",
      "/swagger-resources/*",
      "/configuration/ui",
      "/configuration/security",
      "/swagger-ui/",
      "/webjars/*",
      "/swagger-ui.html"
    )
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
  )
  .cors(withDefaults())
  .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
  .sessionManagement(
    session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  )
  .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
  .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

  return httpSecurity.build();
}

As the authorizeRequests was not configured properly and instead cors(withDefaults()) customizer was getting initialized in the original configuration with csrf().
This caused the authentication allowance and permissions for the pattern matched requests.
